# search query angular 4 rest api

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express

I follow the tutorial that worked: https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/
I need change some information for my application but not working.
follow code:
Component:

```
 export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  articlePosts;
  results: Object;
  searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(
    private searchService: SearchService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
    this.searchService.search(this.searchTerm$) 
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.articlePosts = results.articles;
      });
  }

}
```

Service:

```
 export class SearchService {
  options;
  domain = this.authService.domain;
  queryUrl: string = '?search=';

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  // Function to create headers, add token, to be used in HTTP requests
  createAuthenticationHeaders() {
    this.authService.loadToken(); // Get token so it can be attached to headers
    // Headers configuration options
    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Format set to JSON
        'authorization': this.authService.authToken // Attach token
      })
    });
  }

  search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {

    return this.http.get(this.domain + 'articles/search + this.queryUrl + term').map(res => res.json());

  }
}
```

html:

```
<input
    (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">

<ul *ngIf="results">
  <li *ngFor="let article of articles | slice:0:9">
    <a href="{{ result.latest }}" target="_blank">
      {{ article.nome }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

back end:

```
 router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    var parsedURL = url.parse(req.url, true);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(parsedURL.query));
  });
```

I need query data of my database, someone can help me?

Comment: Please, report the specific error and what you would change

Comment: Not give error, but not show any data.